# Labels on Gridspec

Tags: matplotlib

I have four subplots using the `matplotlib.gridspec` package. However, I am unable to plot the label on the second subplot (`ax2`) and I was wondering how to do this. The code I have is below:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,7))
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1)
gs1.update(left=0.02, right=0.45, hspace=.1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1:,0])
gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1)
gs2.update(left=0.55, right=0.98, hspace=.1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[0, 0])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[1:,0])


ax1.plot(advwbarJFM.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_rho'])[:nz], advwbarJFM.z[:nz], 'b')
ax1.plot(advubarJFM.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_u'])[:nz], advubarJFM.z[:nz], 'b--')
ax1.plot(advvbarJFM.mean(dim=['eta_v','xi_rho'])[:nz], advvbarJFM.z[:nz], 'b-.')
ax1.plot(advwbarJAS.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_rho'])[:nz], advwbarJFM.z[:nz], 'r')
ax1.plot(advubarJAS.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_u'])[:nz], advubarJFM.z[:nz], 'r--')
ax1.plot(advvbarJAS.mean(dim=['eta_v','xi_rho'])[:nz], advvbarJFM.z[:nz], 'r-.')
ax1.set_xlim([-6e-6, 4e-6])
ax1.set_xticks([])
# ax1.set_title(r"Monthly variability")

ax2.plot(advwbarJFM.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_rho'])[nz:], advwbarJFM.z[nz:], 'b', label=r"$\overline{w} \overline{O_2}$")
ax2.plot(advubarJFM.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_u'])[nz:], advubarJFM.z[nz:], 'b--', label=r"$\overline{u} \overline{O_2}$")
ax2.plot(advvbarJFM.mean(dim=['eta_v','xi_rho'])[nz:], advvbarJFM.z[nz:], 'b-.', label=r"$\overline{v} \overline{O_2}$")
ax2.plot(advwbarJAS.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_rho'])[nz:], advwbarJFM.z[nz:], 'r', label=r"$\overline{w} \overline{O_2}$")
ax2.plot(advubarJAS.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_u'])[nz:], advubarJFM.z[nz:], 'r--', label=r"$\overline{u} \overline{O_2}$")
ax2.plot(advvbarJAS.mean(dim=['eta_v','xi_rho'])[nz:], advvbarJFM.z[nz:], 'r-.', label=r"$\overline{v} \overline{O_2}$")
ax2.set_xticks([-6e-6, -4e-6, -2e-6, 0, 2e-6, 4e-6])


ax3.plot(advwppJFM.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_rho'])[:nz], advwppJFM.z[:nz], 'b')
ax3.plot(advuppJFM.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_u'])[:nz], advuppJFM.z[:nz], 'b--')
ax3.plot(advvppJFM.mean(dim=['eta_v','xi_rho'])[:nz], advvppJFM.z[:nz], 'b-.')
ax3.plot(advwppJAS.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_rho'])[:nz], advwppJFM.z[:nz], 'r')
ax3.plot(advuppJAS.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_u'])[:nz], advuppJFM.z[:nz], 'r--')
ax3.plot(advvppJAS.mean(dim=['eta_v','xi_rho'])[:nz], advvppJFM.z[:nz], 'r-.')
ax3.set_xlim([-1.5e-6, 1e-6])
ax3.set_xticks([])
# ax3.set_title(r"Submonthly variability")

ax4.plot(advwppJFM.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_rho'])[nz:], advwppJFM.z[nz:], 'b', label=r"$\overline{w'' O_2''}$")
ax4.plot(advuppJFM.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_u'])[nz:], advuppJFM.z[nz:], 'b--', label=r"$\overline{u'' O_2''}$")
ax4.plot(advvppJFM.mean(dim=['eta_v','xi_rho'])[nz:], advvppJFM.z[nz:], 'b-.', label=r"$\overline{v'' O_2''}$")
ax4.plot(advwppJAS.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_rho'])[nz:], advwppJFM.z[nz:], 'r', label=r"$\overline{w'' O_2''}$")
ax4.plot(advuppJAS.mean(dim=['eta_rho','xi_u'])[nz:], advuppJFM.z[nz:], 'r--', label=r"$\overline{u'' O_2''}$")
ax4.plot(advvppJAS.mean(dim=['eta_v','xi_rho'])[nz:], advvppJFM.z[nz:], 'r-.', label=r"$\overline{v'' O_2''}$")
ax4.set_xticks([-1.5e-6, -1e-6, -5e-7, 0, 5e-7, 1e-6])

plt.suptitle(r"$O_2$ fluxes", y=.95, fontsize=15)
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.show()
```

and the figure is
[image: Subplots using gridspec]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is not a Minimal example because we don't need the data you're plotting and not Complete because you don't provide it. Edit out everything but putting axes into the gridspec and plotting simple dummy data (so there's something for the legend to show).

Comment: Also, you say you can't "plot the label on the second subplot (ax2) " -- you mean the legend? Do you want it on a different axes or on both ax2 and the axes it's on by default?

Comment: If you want your legend in a specific axis as @cphlewis suggested, change your legend command to `ax2.legend()` or `ax4.legend()` or wherever you want one.

Comment: Or just use `plt.figlegend()`: https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20figlegend#matplotlib.pyplot.figlegend